# Create multi-row tables in PHP using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create something like the following:

[image]

But my current code has given me:

[image]

The part in white is what I get with the code below, and the part in black is what I get when I add in two more `<td>` rows. The problem is I can't get 3 pieces of data per row to be created - only vertically or horizontally.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM show_listing");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

echo "<table>

<tr>
<td>".$row['name']."'</td>
</tr>

</table>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

It may be simpler than I think but does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: Whenever possible, please use text instead of graphics.

Answer (score 1):

```
$c = 0;
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    if ($c%3 == 0) {
        if ($c) echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
    }
    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";

    $c++;
}
if ($c) echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct idea.  You do not want the  declaration in the while loop as the result is that you will get multiple tables.

So I moved the table declarations outside of the while loop.  I also made the  declarations conditional based on the current column.  You can now set the variable $columns to however many columns you want.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM show_listing");
echo "<table>"
$columns=3;
$current_column=1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

if($current_column==1) {
    echo "<tr>";
}

echo "<td>".$row['name']."'</td>";

if($current_column==$columns) {
     echo "</tr>";
     $current_column=1;
} else 
     $current_column++;
}
echo "</table>

mysqli_close($con);
```